# PlantUML: Packages next to each other, components in a list

Tags: package, uml, modeling, plantuml

I want to have 2 packages next to each other and the containing components among each other.
Goal (Draft):

[image]

Code:

```
@startuml
left to right direction 
() Mechanical
() Hydraulical
() Electrical
package Machine{
    Mechanical )-left- [Turning Disc]  
    Mechanical )-left- [Vent]
    Electrical )-left-[Baler_ECU]
    Hydraulical )-left-[Arm] 
}

package Tractor{
    [Engine] -right- Mechanical
    [Hydraulics] -right- Hydraulical
    [Tractor_ECU] -right- Electrical
}

@enduml
```

Current Result of this code: 
[image]

Thank you for any help

Comment: the way is easy, stop to loose your time to use that drawing tool having intrinsically limited possible outputs due to its wau to work, and use a UML tool both allowing you to do UML (which is much more than just a picture which is the alone result with PlantUML) and to draw as you expect ... ;-)

Comment: The drawing is all I want, so where's the problem? There's no plan of programming something, it's just to visualize a real life issue

Comment: Whatever, you can do that more easily and as you want with an UML tool. I am sorry to not have the answer for planUML but probably there is *no* answer because you request something impossible with it, because of the way it works

Answer (score 2):

Try to use "hidden" attribute

```
@startuml
left to right direction 

rectangle interface{
    () Mechanical
    () Hydraulical
    () Electrical
}

package Machine{
    Mechanical )-- [Turning Disc]  
    Mechanical )-- [Vent]
    Electrical )--[Baler_ECU]
    Hydraulical )--[Arm] 
}

package Tractor{
    [Engine] -- Mechanical
    [Hydraulics] -- Hydraulical
    [Tractor_ECU] -- Electrical
}

interface -[hidden]- Machine
Tractor -[hidden]- interface
@enduml
```

[image]